# vmc not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

I installed Ruby 1.9.3 and also installed vmc successfully as per instructions at http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/installing-vmc.html
But when I try to run vmc with "Start Command Prompt with Ruby" cmd, I get 'vmc' not recognised error, I know this usually means I need to add vmc to system path but I can't find where it is installed.

Running windows xp

Comment: Ok, I understand you're in the command prompt with ruby window. Let's see what "gem -v" and "ruby -v" reveals, as a start. You can also do a "gem uninstall vmc" and it will reveal your vmc installations. You could take another step and uninstall vmc, then reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a "gem uninstall vmc" and it will reveal your vmc installations. You could take another step and uninstall vmc, then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

on my machine it is here:)

C:>which vmc

/cygdrive/c/Ruby193/bin/vmc